# Не получается вызвать метод из с++ через java native interface,вызывается исключение

Tags: java, c++, jni

[image: исключение]    #include "pch.h"

```
FARPROC loadDll(LPCWSTR dllname, LPCSTR  procName)
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Rus");
    HMODULE dll = LoadLibraryW(dllname);
    if (!dll) {
        cout << "dll не загружена";
        system("pause");
    }

    FARPROC farproc = GetProcAddress(dll, procName);
    if (!farproc) {
        cout << "функция из dll не загружена";
        system("pause");
    }

    return farproc;
    FreeLibrary(dll);

}





jint java(JavaVM **vm, void **env ) {
    typedef jint(*jNI_CreateJavaVM)(JavaVM **, void **, void *);



    JavaVMInitArgs vm_args;
    JavaVMOption* options = new JavaVMOption[4];
    vm_args.version = 0x000c0000;
    vm_args.options = options;
    vm_args.nOptions = 4;
    vm_args.ignoreUnrecognized = FALSE;

    options[0].optionString = (char*)"-Djava.compiler=NONE";           
    options[1].optionString = (char*)"-Djava.class.path=C:/Program Files/Java/jdk-12.0.2/lib";  
    options[2].optionString = (char*)"-Djava.library.path=c:";   
    options[3].optionString = (char*)"-verbose:jni";



    jNI_CreateJavaVM   JNI_CreateJavaVM = (jNI_CreateJavaVM)loadDll(L"C:/Program Files/Java/jdk-12.0.2/bin/server/jvm.dll", "JNI_CreateJavaVM");
    jint i = JNI_CreateJavaVM(vm, env, (void*)&vm_args);


    return i;
    delete options;

}




int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    JavaVM **vm;
    JNIEnv  *env;

    jint j = java(vm, (void**)env);
    jclass cls = env->FindClass("java.base/java/io/PrintWriter");
    jmethodID method=env->GetMethodID(cls, "println",("Ljava/lang/String;)V");

    cout << "" << endl;
    return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

У вас ошибка в вызове функции `jint j = java(vm, (void**)env);` В этом месте вы кастуете обычный указатель к указателю на указатель, а надо добавить операцию взятия адреса. Также неправильно объявлен указатель на JavaVM - он должен быть объявлен как обычный указатель, и при передаче параметра тоже не забываем взятие адреса.

```
JavaVM *vm;
JNIEnv *env;
jint j = java(&vm, (void**)&env);
```

Comment: Все ровно тоже самое.

Comment: Да действительно есть ещё ошибка, поправил ответ. Рекомендую воспользоваться официальной документацией: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/jniTOC.html

Comment: Заработало большое спасибо.